# Will Apple Music 3 month trial carry over if changing plans?

Tags: apple-music, family-sharing

A Family linked account recently signed up to Apple Music for a 3 month free trial, but selected the **Individual** account option rather than **Family**, so only that single account has access to the trial.

I want to change the subscription to **Family**, but don't want it to see that as a purchase "now" and end the free trial.

Some Googling around this found me a Reddit question from 4 years ago (indicates it would carry over), but I'd rather not hang my hopes on old information.  Hopefully one of our members has a more recent experience with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Apple Support and they advised that the free trial *would* carry over.

I can confirm that having changed the subscription that this has worked as expected.